Spring Boot OAuth - JOSE header typ (type) JOSE not allowed
I am developing a common Spring Boot OAuth client app. There is also my Angular applications and Spring Boot resource servers.
I initiate OAuth from Angular, it redirects to Auth page(Company OAuth) server and it then redirects to the Angular application with code and other stuff.
The Angular application sends the code to my Spring Boot client application, which returns access token, ID token etc.
Then to my resource server, I put the ID Token as Bearer token to access any endpoint. The thing is, this worked with Google Auth server.
But when I send the token, I am getting unauthorized(sending from Postman). The cookie is showing
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: JOSE header typ (type) JOSE not allowed", 

For the WWW-Authenticate header.
And in my resource server logs :
o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider [ajp-nio-8009-exec-399] Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid


Below is my configuration :

@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig 
{
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        
        //.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt());
        
        return http.build();
    }


and the applications properties :
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri={COMPANY_AUTH}
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri={COMPANY_AUTH}/jwk

{COMPANY_AUTH} is the same as the 'iss' in my ID Token.
The problem it seems that, below is the ID Token headers :
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JOSE"
}

I am using Spring Boot v2.6.7
Please help. What is wrong with this ?
Thanks in advance.

The value ”JOSE” is not a valid value in the typ parameter. The field is used to define what mediattypes the jwt containes. This is defined in the RFC for jwts https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-5.1 so whover created the jwt has done wrong and should fix it

So the Auth server ID Token "typ" should be "JWT" without exception ?

Or JWE or no typ field at all as the docs say

Is there any way to use decoder ? I have seen some examples like the NimbusDecoder but it isn't working ?
Or is there a way to change the "typ"with Public Key ?

The JWT is faulty, change the JWT.
